# How to access nested #document in html?

Tags: html, document, queryselector

Hi I want to use `document.querySelector()` to find `span id='t1'` and I don't know how to access the `#document` element and anything inside it. Is there a way to select elements inside `#document` ?

Here I am using html clock from 'timeanddate' website.

[image: firefox inspector tool]

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing here with an **iFrame**, which is a piece of website into HTML.

You can access it with this kind of method :
`document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document`